# Can onDestroy followed by onCreate happen on the same class instance?

Tags: android

I was wondering, during activity re-creation, or fragment re-creation or service re-creation, is there a possibility, that the same instance of class being re-used?

For example

```
//public class HomeFragment extends Activity {
//public class HomeFragment extends Service {
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Can instrumentSearchMonitor has possibility to become null right here, due to onDestroy?
        instrumentSearchMonitor.doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        instrumentSearchMonitor = null;
    }

    private InstrumentSearchMonitor instrumentSearchMonitor = new InstrumentSearchMonitor();
}
```

For the above case, is there a possibility that `onCreate` will encounter a null object, due to nullify action in `onDestroy`?

My testing is, after `onDestroy` is being called, the next call of `onCreate` will happen on the different class instance.

I was wondering, is there any possibility, that the next call of `onCreate`, will happen on the same class instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `onDestroy()` has been called, the fragment is going to be completely removed and can not be reused.

This can be seen in the Fragment lifecycle:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRxIQ.png

In the image you can seee that `onDestroyView()` can be called, and then it goes back to onCreateView(), but once `onDestroy()` is called, you're safe to null/delete whatever you want in that class instance.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code above onDestroy

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        instrumentSearchMonitor = null;
        super.onDestroy();

    }
```